# How to send the uploaded file to the printer using angular js?? other than window.print()

Tags: javascript

How to send the uploaded file to the printer using angular js other than window.print()?

I have a option of upload for any type of files like .doc,.pdf or .txt and i want to send the uploaded file to the printer on button click

Comment: did you use $window.print() ?

Answer (score 0):

From standard browser-based JavaScript code, you have no other options for printing than

- `window.print`, which you've said you don't want to use
- Telling the user to open and then print the file

Comment: $scope.printFunction = function (filename)
  { 
   var doc = window.open(filename);
   doc.print();
  }

Comment: are you saying to do like this?

Comment: @JayasriSomasundaram: No, I'm just saying you only have two options for printing from browsers right now. Which you use is very specific to what you're doing.